# android studio change background image for multiple images

Tags: android, image

I have 5 images in the drawable folder (bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, bg5), bg1 is my default background.

I want to change the the image of the background in order eatch time I click the button and when it arrive to the final image it should go again to the first image,

for example if I cliked the button it should set bg2 as background and if I clicked it again it should set bg3 as background and so on,

I tried the below code but it only change the background image one time.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int x = 0;

            while(x < 5){

             x ++;
                // Give image name that you want to show on button click
                layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg+x);

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: you should save the value of x. In this way you are always  starting from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
// declare the varibale globally, or else everytime the onClick is called it will be reset to 0 
int x = 1;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int bg = 0;

                // are we larger than 5? lets start again at 1 :)
                if (x == 6) x = 1;

                if (x == 1) bg = R.drawable.bg1;
                if (x == 2) bg = R.drawable.bg2;
                if (x == 3) bg = R.drawable.bg3;
                if (x == 4) bg = R.drawable.bg4;
                if (x == 5) bg = R.drawable.bg5;

                layout.setBackgroundResource(bg);

                // lets increment you for the next round
                x++;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me after changing x to final

Comment: do you have any idea how to save thae last choosen image after closing the app

Comment: @arater2000 https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences try sharedpreferences. Id assume you just save the R.drawable.bg1 or whatever, which will save the int id of the resource. If you need more complex structures then id recommend using the sqllite database of android.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `x` as a global variable. You set `x` in function so it is always `0`.

```
int x = 0; //global variable in activity/fragment

...

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              x ++;
              x %= 5;
              if (x==0) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg1);
              else if (x==1) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg2);
              else if (x==2) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg3);
              else if (x==3) layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg4);
              else layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg5);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you really do R.drawable.bg+x? I mean values in the R file are generated ids, so I assume you cant simply add 1 to it and expect it to work all the time, except by pure luck and prayers

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Yeah it can't be done I think but in question, code it's written like this so I write in this way but I think it is only to make it short. Normally it has to be done with if as You have written

Comment: @DavidKroukamp What? He wrote in his question " but it only changes the background image one time". So I think that He knows how to set image resource and the only problem is with local variable

Comment: That's like watching a person drown in an ocean, with a shark circling them and you simply threw them a life jacket and jet off.

Comment: The main (and I think the only one) problem in this question was a local variable not setting resources. So to make code shorter I wrote an answer in a way like a questioner ‍♂️

Comment: Removed my downvote and upvoted. Thanks for the update.